# Volley + Multidex Application Name in Manifest

Tags: android, android-volley

Folks my project used Volley lib to show thumb images in a recyclelistview, however my app has grown big and I had to use Multidex flag to true, and I had to remove

```
<!--android:name=".controller.AppController"-->
```

and use:

```
manifest.xml

<application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"

myfragmentclass.java
...
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
...

AppController.java

public class AppController extends Application {
...
}
```

so when my framgment instantiates the volley object it gets an NPE since there is no constructor for the class.

Is there a way I can make it work or should I use another lib for loading images from network dinamically when user scrolls the list?

thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can! Your `.controller.AppController` initialize all instance for volley and each other. Nomarly `AppController extend Application`, in your case you need make `AppController extend MultiDexApplication`, !remember alway call `super fuction()` if you overider a function, then make your `manifest.xml` normal like first case `android:name=".controller.AppController"`

Comment: it didnt work I got the following error message

RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application mobile.pm.myapp.controller.AppController: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "mobile.pm.myapp.controller.AppController" on path: DexPathList

Comment: Not is correct clean project, you need put "multiDexEnabled true" or your compilations will be slows